# Return jsonb as rows in Postgres

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, jsonb

I have a json column that holds an array of objects containing a 'name' attribute. I'm trying to build a query that can extract the unique names out of all the objects, across all rows.

Here is what the data looks like:

```
[{
  "date": "2022-06-14T12:51:24.424Z",
  "name": "review_1"
}]

[{
  "date": "2022-06-14T12:50:56.454Z",
  "name": "review_3"
}, {
  "date": "2022-06-14T12:51:10.695Z",
  "name": "review_6"
}]

[{
  "date": "2022-06-14T12:51:57.997Z",
  "name": "review_3"
}]

[{
  "date": "2022-06-14T12:52:17.442Z",
  "name": "review_1"
}, {
  "date": "2022-06-14T12:54:35.239Z",
  "name": "review_9
}]
```

My approach is to get all the names as individual rows like this so I can find the distincts.

```
name    ||  date
review_1    2022-06-14T12:51:24.424Z
review_3    2022-06-14T12:50:56.454Z
review_6    2022-06-14T12:51:10.695Z
review_3    2022-06-14T12:51:57.997Z
review_1    2022-06-14T12:52:17.442Z
review_9    2022-06-14T12:54:35.239Z
```

I've tried using **jsonb_array_elements** following this post [postgres + jsonb + get values of key from multidimentional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39042151/postgres-jsonb-get-values-of-key-from-multidimentional-array/39044227#39044227) but it looks like that is for multidimentional arrays and I cannot get it to work.

Comment: Please show us the query that you tried and the error message that you got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to guess what kind of problems you have encountered, but the use of the function seems quite simple.

```sql
select elem->>'name' as "name", elem->>'date' as "date"
from my_table
cross join jsonb_array_elements(json_col) as arr(elem);
```

Test it in [Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=0a66fedfeed95eb20600ef0b0de843ca)

Comment: that's it!  had a feeling jsonb_array_elements was the function but never used it in a cross join.  thanks